# Python Schedule not work in Flask

Tags: python, flask, wsgi, schedule

I am importing `Schedule` into `Flask`. My project contains `WSGI` however I know little about the relationship between `Flask` and `WSGI`. Now I have three main files:

- `wsgi.py`: Automatically generated by other tool.
- `app.py` : I put client request here.
- `test.py`: Used to test `Schedule`.

I want to start a task which is a long task when server launch. Here is the part of `wsgi.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from threading import Thread
import test


t = Thread(target=test.job)
t.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...
```

As you see I start a thread and let the job work in it.Here is my `test.py`.

```
import schedule


def job():
    schedule.every(1).seconds.do(pr)


def pr():
    print("I'm working...")
```

**My problem is that the `job` never starts.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out my problem.I never let schedule execute jobs. Now `wsgi.py` looks like this.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from threading import Thread
import test

schedule.every(1).seconds.do(test.job)
t = Thread(target=test.run_schedule)
t.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...
```

And `test.py`:

```
import schedule
import time

start_time = time.time()


def job():
    print("I'm working..." + str(time.time() - start_time))


def run_schedule():
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```

In order to work in separate thread, I create a thread and in this thread I loop every 1ms. In loop, `schedule` invoke `run_pending` to call the `job` if time out (in my case it's 1s).